# Google App Engine returning odd values from datastore

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to do a simple save string to datastore, redirect on that entity's key, then fetch it in the next handler. When I make the call in PDFHandler to fetch the string (a.name()) "w" is returned everytime, no matter what I enter.

```
class Pdf(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class InputHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('cert_form.html')

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')

        if name:
            a = Pdf(name=name)
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/key=%s' % a.key())
        else:
            error = "Please enter your full name."
            self.render('cert_form.html')

class PDFHandler(Handler):
    def get(self, id):
        a = db.Key.from_path('Pdf', id)


        self.response.write(a.name())

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', InputHandler),
    (r'/key=(.)+', PDFHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: What  value you see in the appengine datastore viewer for the name field on your PDF entity?

Comment: It gives the names "Bobby Smith", "John Adams" etc. Here's another question. I've got to the point where I can return the entity key. How do I simply look up the entity properties (name, id) from this? When I enter post = key.get()  I get
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Looks like when you call key.get() - key is a string and not a Key object.  If you are getting the key from the url - you will need to take that string and create a Key object for that entity before calling get().

Comment: Is there a reason you **must** use old crufty `db` rather than the vastly preferred, newer `ndb`?  I'm **so** rusty on `db` that I'd need a long refresh cycle to help w/that -- I've used nothing but `ndb` for so many years!  Also, I'm dubious about what exactly your `r'/key=(.)+'` captures -- repeating the group rather than its contents, what a weird RE pattern?!  Why not a normal `r'/key=(.+)'`, capturing w/o doubt the repeated contents?  At least try logging `id` in `PDFHandler` to see if it is what you think it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PDFHandler when you do

```
a = db.Key.from_path('Pdf', id)
```

What you are getting is the Key object not the entity yet.

To get the Pdf entity you can do the below

```
pdf = db.get(a)
```

Then you can access fields on pdf  like pdf.name etc.